# macOS Big Sur Ignoring ffi-1.12.2 because its extensions are not built

Tags: cocoa, command-line, macos-big-sur

I updated macOS to Big Sur when I try to update cocoa gem I got this error please check attached screenshot [Command line error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uEWYt.png)

Comment: https://www.biteinteractive.com/how-to-get-started-with-pods/ You need to stop using system ruby immediately.